# What's wrong with this mouse look function?

Tags: unity-game-engine, quaternions

I've been toying with iterations of this for a few weeks, but it's still busted so I thought id reach out for some help.
This performs as expected except for one glaring issue: the output sensitivity appears to be super pitch dependent.

`

```
        //Grab mouse input
        float rotateHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
        float rotateVertical = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

        Vector3 rotation = new Vector3(rotateVertical, rotateHorizontal, 0);

        transform.Rotate(sensitivity * Time.deltaTime * rotation);

        Vector3 eAngles = transform.eulerAngles;
        float pitch = eAngles.x;
        pitch = ClampAngle(pitch, -camClamp, camClamp); 
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(pitch, eAngles.y, eAngles.z);
```

`

What am I missing? I'm pretty sure it's not the clamp angle function since I stole it from a reputable source.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rotations are hard!
I think it was a rotation order problem.
Switched to quaternions, problem remained, then found [this](https://twitter.com/freyaholmer/status/1445398542286217222?lang=en) lovely thread and reordered the operands.

```
        originalRotation = transform.localRotation;
    //Grab mouse input
    float rotateHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    float rotateVertical = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

    Quaternion xQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotateHorizontal, Vector3.up);
    Quaternion yQuaternion = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotateVertical, -Vector3.right);

    transform.localRotation = xQuaternion * originalRotation * yQuaternion;

    Vector3 eAngles = transform.eulerAngles;
    float pitch = eAngles.x;
    pitch = ClampAngle(pitch, -camClamp, camClamp); 
    transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(pitch, eAngles.y, eAngles.z);
```

Thank you freya holmer

Order matters in quaternion multiplication!